# SetLabel doesn't work on a JPopupMenu

Tags: java, eclipse, label, jpopupmenu

For me the `setLabel` method of the java's `JPopupMenu` does not work.

Here is a simple popup menu example:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpleexampleofJPopupMenu.htm

Inside is:

```
public JPopupMenu popup;
popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setLabel("Justification");
```

But when I launch the script, my popup menu has no label "Justification":

[image]

However, the documentation says this is the right way to define labels:

```
public void setLabel(String label)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#setLabel%28java.lang.String%29

I am using **Eclipse 3.7.2**, with **JRE 1.7_067**.

Of course, the same problem occurs on my own project...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Comment: The setLabel documentation says 'Different look and feels may choose to display or not display this', most choose not to display. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8546073/2670892)

Comment: Thank you very much @greg-449 !
From a java beginner :)